# Turn off raspberry Pi with Kodi remotely

Tags: raspberry-pi, kodi

Let me explain my problem: I have a raspberry Pi with Kodi installed and I use it with a IPTV service. This service only allow me to use it in one device at a time and sometimes I want to use it on my phone. 
I'd like to be able to turn off my raspberry remotely so I can watch it in my phone whenever I want. I tried to create a web server that would allow me to run a script that would turn off the device but I can't access it because the raspberry IP takes me to some kodi stuff.

[image]

So to sum up, I'd like to go to my raspberry IP with Kodi installed, press a button and turn off the device. The web stuff I can take care of.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is the button you want to press? On the Pi? If so, where does the remote stuff come into it?

Comment: As I mentioned I want to go into my raspberry ip using my phone and show a simple html file with a button that would run a .sh command to turn off the raspberry. I think it's not possible because I'm using Kodi/Openelec and has many limitations, I would have to install XBMC in Raspbian.

Comment: You need to run the server on a different port than the default one (80).

Comment: emiliomarin : OK; when you said "button" I thought you meant a physical, hardware button on the unit itself. In your case, if the Kodi infrastructure is already implementing a webserver, and you can't get to it to modify it, you'll need to use a separate webserver, listening on a different port, as @mtman says. You might be able to install one of the ordinary webservers (Apache HTTPD, for example) and just configure it to use a different port. Or write some code (I would use C, but it's straightforward in Python) that implements a simple HTTP server, using a port of your choice.

Comment: Maybe run a simple Python server on a different port from Kodi with an on/off button - it's only a couple of lines https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way to do this is to have a `VPN tunnel` that lets you access your internal network. This is much safer than opening up a port to Kodi on your router. It would just attract every bot and hacker out there.

Once you have a working VPN tunnel between your home network and your smartphone, just use a Remote Control App to shut Kodi down cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Kodi remote app for your mobile device. E.g. Kore (official remote app for Android) does have a shutdown button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and easy way is to install [dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com) in your **Raspberry Pi** and access via dataplicity web or the app (Android or iOS) to the Terminal and use the command: `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo poweroff`